# Out of memory (realloc failed) when cloning new repo

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

In SourceTree I am getting the following error when cloning a repo from a new machine:

[image: Git out of memory error]

I have tried editing the global config file using absolutely every suggestion on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, including:

```
pack.deltaCacheSize = 1g
pack.packSizeLimit = 1g
pack.windowMemory = 1g
core.packedGitLimit = 1g
core.packedGitWindowSize = 1g
```

As well as

```
core.preloadIndex = false;
```

And

```
pack.window = 0
```

And nothing works. Anything else I can try? There is a large maya model in the repo or something that is causing this but it has to be there...

Comment: see this: [git out of memory on checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360328/git-out-of-memory-on-checkout)

Comment: Yep, I have tried all of those settings already, it seems to be a different issue in my case

Comment: In SourceTree, are you using the Embedded or the System git?

Comment: Good point Gino! Especially if it is in Windows.

Comment: Apparently, there's an [existing ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-6778) created for SourceTree on Windows, which seems fairly similar to yours. Their workaround might also work for you.

Comment: I ended up "solving" it just by downloading a .zip of the repo and then adding the remote URL in SourceTree. But I don't know if I should put this as an answer, since it's kindof a workaround and doesn't solve the underlying problem.