# Sha1 & Out Of Memory Git Push

Tags: git, ssh, version-control

I have setup a bare repo and have am actively using it via ssh. I've noticed my latest set of commits cannot push to this repo (file size?) but a smaller commit can push to another repo on the same machine.

I have increased some pack parameters to 1024m and ensured there is enough memory available on the remote machine.

> $ git push
>   $ git push warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has
>   changed in Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this
>   message and maintain the traditional behavior, use:
>
> git config --global push.default matching
>
> To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>
> git config --global push.default simple
>
> When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
>   to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.
>
> Since Git 2.0, Git defaults to the more conservative 'simple'
>   behavior, which only pushes the current branch to the corresponding
>   remote branch that 'git pull' uses to update the current branch.
>
> See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further
>   information. (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the
>   similar mode 'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older
>   versions of Git)
>
> foo@foo's password: Counting objects: 104, done. Compressing
>   objects: 100% (100/100), done. fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed
>   (tried to allocate 914457600 bytes) fatal: sha1 file '' write
>   error: Invalid argument error: failed to push some refs to
>   'ssh://foo@foo'

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10292903/1256452 and/or http://stackoverflow.com/q/8855317/1256452 (the first says specifically "Windows" but the answers apply everywhere).  Your problem is occurring on your system, not the remote, but because there is a very large file (about 1GB) it may occur on the remote once you've fixed it locally.

Comment: Would git not be able to pack this file even after the config changes?

Comment: It's mainly a matter of needing to set these in multiple config files (based on the machine doing the git operations, and its support for really big malloc()s).  (Ideally git would use a different approach to files whose size exceeds a few MB, or maybe 100MB, or some such, but it doesn't today.)