# Why does Git Clone Fails Even with small repositories?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-clone, cloning

I have checked a few questions around this area. It seems malloc fail for insufficient memory is a common issue for massive files, and there are some work-arounds.

But my repository size (containing a readme, a few shell scripts, python scripts and config files, all texts), as reported by GitLab is  19.4 MB. When I run

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/username/project.git
```

the terminal echoes

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1744830464 bytes)
```

which is about 1.5GB. Where do these things come from? Not only I need a work-arounds, but I am also curious whether there is any *hidden* content in my repository which interferes with a smooth cloning. Also, so far it is a pretty fresh project and I only have one branch.

Using git version 2.19.0.windows.1 on windows 7

But the error does not show up on Linux staging clusters or even in Linux laptops using same configuration. From some further research, it seems the error might have something to do with editing file permissions on my Linux copy, and setting  core.filemode to true. I did it because I do have to frequently alter the permissions of files in the production server and wanted these changes to be reflected in the repository.

Comment: What is your OS and git version?

Comment: The on giving the problem is running windows 7 git version 2.19. I added some further information in the question.

Comment: Can you check with Git 2.19.2 or Git 2.20-rc0?

Comment: Have you tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12672320/9534591)? i.e. git config pack.windowMemory 50m

Comment: The Windows PC is from my company and without any admin privilege. So it is a lot of hassle to do even simple things, such as wiping and re-installing Git etc. Anyway, the problem started after I set core.filemode to true. I have reset it back and also set http.postbuffer=5m, according to some advice. I am not sure about the implications, but now the problem is gone.