# What is the solutionn to this error fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1048576000 bytes) when pushing to heroku?

Tags: ruby, git, heroku

I am trying to push a repo to heroku using the following command:
`git push -u heroku master`
but I keep getting the error below:

```
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 1048576000 bytes)
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 1012 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sheltered-cliffs-69598.git'
```

the repo is barely bigger than 1MB. It's basically a simple hello-world application built with ruby so it only has `config.ru`, `Gemfile`, `Gemfile.lock` and `hello.rb` files, nothing else. What could be causing such an error and how to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push Out of memory, malloc failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855317/git-push-out-of-memory-malloc-failed)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
git gc --auto --prune=today --aggressive 
git repack 
git config --global http.postbuffer 524288000 
git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m
```